# Data Size vs Query Execution

Tags: sql

I have table with 30 Million records in it with a size of ~20 GB. It takes approximately 30 minutes to execute and provide the result ( ran `Select * from table`).

How do I see what needs to be improved on this aspect as the query reads all the data I don't think index can help me.

Is it reasonable amount of time?

It drains my C Drive to get data, does it sound like common behavior?

Comment: What exactly to you calculate by this full table scan? If only a few columns are used, there is an option to include datafields into the index (so only the index is read, not the whole 20GB ... but increases insert/update times and disk usage)

Comment: I have this table passed to report with entire data and the table is created for report so all the columns are required.

Comment: What possible sense can anyone make of a 30 million row report?

Comment: @SamithCValsalan: I´m pretty sure you are summing up some values by groups etc ... why not writing a stored procedure to aggregate the data as needed and then just use this "summary" table?

Comment: We use Spotfire and if we use stored procedure it use on demand concept and data fetching will be happening in each filter. the way we have implemented is readig data directly from table so using schedule update Spotfire read data and store it in its memory. So end user can access the reports without lag

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I guess at this point the different dimensions for last couple of years data is making the data huge, I need to revisit if we can reduce it or not. But here I am trying to understand the time taking for 30M for 30 minutes is expected or not.

Comment: Which SQL server are you using? What is the schema for the table? What have you done to profile the query?

Comment: The time taken to read 30million records will be limited by the speed of your discs, speed of your network and the amount of contention (i.e. other things happening on the server).  If it's years worth of data, why not read just what has changed since your last read and keep it handy.  In fact, why use SQL at all if you aren't really using the power of SQL to do any filtering?  Surely it would perform better as a flat-file kept on the machine you are reading it to.

Comment: As a general comment, 30 minutes to read 30 million records definitely has room for improvement. If you're saying it 'drains your C drive' then it sounds like the database server is insufficiently provisioned to be running a database with 30 million records. You could elaborate further and indicate how much memory and CPU the database server has.